# In Spacemacs, how do I insert a newline, without entering insert mode?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

In Vim, you can bind `Enter` key to insert a newline without entering `insert mode`. how can you do this in Spacemacs.

Or how to remap keys in general in Spacemacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "RET") 'spacemacs/evil-insert-line-below)
```

to insert a line below and stay at the same position, or

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "RET")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'spacemacs/evil-insert-line-below)
    (evil-next-line)))
```

to insert a line below and go to the new line.

Comment: Add (call-interactively 'evil-insert-state) to get into insert mode after adding a new line

Answer (score 17):

In Spacemacs, it is also possible to insert a new line while remaining in `normal` state with the wildly useful command `spacemacs/evil-insert-line-below`.

It is bound to <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> in Vim mode and <kbd>M-m</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> in Emacs mode.

Preceding that command with a numerical argument will insert more than one new line, e.g. <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> will insert four new lines.

Comment: sweet. any way to make the cursor move to the new line though?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> to append a new line below. It is equivalent to <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.

Also you can add one line above by <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>.